# turn random matrices to positive semidefinite

Tags: python, numpy, torch

I have a problem when i generate random matrices and turn them into positive semidefinite. If we take a random matrix Q and then multiply it with its transpose then the outcome should be positive semidefinite ( no negative eigenvalues) However when i print some random eigenvalues i see that i have negative ones. Does my code has something wrong? Also I want to save the max values of the eigenvalues into a vector. My Q random matrices are integers and the eigenvalues from what i ve seen are real numbers and the complex part is always 0. However i get a warning as well. Let me show you my code first

```
#here i create a random torch with N matrices of n by n size
Q = torch.randint(0, 10, size=(N, n, n))

#here i initialize my vector for the max eigenvalues
max=np.zeros(N)

#here i create a loop where i multiply each Q matrix in my torch with its transpose
for i in range(0,N):
    Q[i] = Q[i]*Q[i].t()
    #here i find my eigenvalues and save the max into my vector max
    val,vec=lg.eig(Q[i])
    max[i]= np.amax(val)
```

The warning i get is

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

and my eigenvalues i print them from the console with the command

```
lg.eig(Q[0])
However i see for example
(array([120.20198423+0.j,  -1.93985888+0.j,  34.73787466+0.j])

Which has a negative value
```

Comment: OK, so I don't know torch, but from reading your code, I'd say that the problem might be you transpose your matrix, instead of conjugate transposing, given you have complex values there. This could also explain why you are getting the warning related to complex values.
Which line does the warning come from?

Comment: Does `Q[i]*Q[i].t()` perform matrix multiplication or is it an element wise product? IIRC, in numpy we need to use @ to do matrix multiplication

Comment: Hey you are right. When i used @ i no longer have negative values!  Regarding the warning now, I have it on the line  with the command max[i]= np.amax(val)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a random integer matrix, but your warning message implies `Q` contains complex values.

As such, in order to create a positive semidefinite matrix you must multiply `Q` by its *conjugate* transpose `torch.conj(Q).t()` (this is equivalent to the transpose across the reals).

Also, you are computing the dot product by using `*`, for matrix multiplication use `@`, `torch.mm` or `torch.matmul`.